# How to get a nested object with string in dotation format in JS (ES6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How to efficiently assign a variable depth nested object only with a value and a string of type:

```
const names = 'obj.source.name'
const value = 'myValue'
```

To get:

```
{ obj: { source: { name: 'myValue' } } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function nestObject(names, value) {
  if (names.length === 0) {
    return value;
  }
  return nestObject(names.splice(0, names.length - 1), { [names.splice(-1)]: value })
}

function nestedProps(name, value) {
  if (Array.isArray(name)) {
    return nestObject(name, value);
  } else {
    return nestObject(name.split('.'), value);
  }
};
console.log(nestedProps('obj.source.name', 'myValue'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `reduce()` method.

```js
const names = 'obj.source.name'
const value = 'myValue'

function nestObj(keys, val) {
  var o = {}, k = keys.split('.')
  return k.reduce((r, e, i) => r[e] || (r[e] = (k.length-1 != i) ? {} : val), o), o
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(nestObj(names, value), 0, 4))
```

Comment: Smart answer ! Didn't think about reduce

Answer (score 0):

I personnaly use [Lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash) for that kind of things.

https://lodash.com/docs/#set does what you are looking for.

`_.set({}, 'obj.source.name', 'myValue');`

Comment: Well, you need an object for this. I use my solution to pass an arbitrary hash to Redux reducers through an action

Comment: I thought you already had an object.
If you wish to create a new object, just write an empty object as the first arg: `_.set({}, 'obj.source.name', 'myValue');`

Comment: Nice solution !

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getObject(path, value) {
  let obj = {}, // the result object (the one to return)
      _r = obj; // will serve as a reference to a depth

  let parts = path.split('.'), // split the path
      last = parts.pop(); // remove the last one and store it to be used later to store the value
  
  parts.forEach(p => { // for each part (depth) in the path
    _r[p] = {}; // assign an empty object to this depth
    _r = _r[p]; // store its reference to be used as the current depth
  });
  _r[last] = value; // set the value at the last depth
  
  return obj;
}


const names = 'obj.source.name';
const value = 'myValue';

console.log(getObject(names, value));
```